# Difference between $L^2[0,2\pi]$ and $L^2(S^1)$

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, fourier-series, spectral-theory

I'm cofused with the definition of the spaces $L^2(S^1)$ and $L^2[0,2\pi]$. I have read that we can consider $L^2(S^1)$ as the elements $f \in L^2[0,2\pi]$ such that $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ . But  in my opinion the latter does not have sense because in $L^2[0,2\pi]$ we can't talk about point values.

Could you explain me what is the difference between $L^2(S^1)$ and $L^2[0,2\pi]$, please? I will appreciate if you can give me a reference related to this question.

Comment: The condition you mention is not for $L^2$, but for continuous functions, because as you mentioned, it doesn’t make sense to evaluate arbitrary $L^2$ functions pointwise.

Comment: $L^2([0,2\pi])$ and $L^2(S^1)$ are isomorphic, because any function in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ can be approximated in the $L^2$ norm by a continuous function $f$ with $f(0)=f(2\pi)=0$.  Remember that approximation in $L^2$ is approximation by area, so even if an $L^2$ function $g$ you're approximating is not close at $0$ and $2\pi$, you can straighten it out at the edges to make the endpoints close with the area of the 'straightening' as small as you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$L^2([0,2\pi])$ is the completion of $C([0,2\pi])$ with respect to the $L^2$-norm. Now $C(S^1)$ can be viewed as the subspace of $C([0,2\pi])$ consisting of functions such that $f(0)=f(2\pi)$. Moreover, $L^2(S^1)$ is the completion of $C(S^1)$ with respect to the $L^2$-norm. This is the sense in which $L^2(S^1)$ can be viewed as a subspace of $L^2([0,2\pi])$.

Comment: but one should also explain why the reverse “inclusion” holds (unless of course it’s left as an exercise :).

Comment: Which inclusion are you asking about?

Comment: you mentioned why there is an inclusion $L^2(S^1)\hookrightarrow L^2([0,2\pi])$, but not the reverse.

Comment: Right, John Doe mentions the reason in a comment to OP. I'll type it up later if I have the energy.

Comment: Thank you. Does it means that these spaces are the same space? Please read my Edit.

Comment: Although $C([0,2\pi])$ and $C(S^1)$ are different, after completion $L^2([0,2\pi])=L^2(S^1)$